Linking GetUILanguageFallbackList API with MinGW-w64
I'm trying to use the Windows GetUILanguageFallbackList API with MinGW-w64.
Here is a very minimalistic example of calling the API:
#include <windows.h>
#include <muiload.h>

int main() {
    GetUILanguageFallbackList(NULL, 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}

Now, I'm not expecting that code to actually do anything useful, since I haven't supplied a valid combination of parameters. But all I'm trying to do at this point, is get the code to compile and link. I actually have a longer example which attempts to use the API properly, but I created the above minimal version just to reproduce my linking issue. So I save that as uilang0.c.
But when I try to compile, linking fails with the below error:
# gcc -o uilang0 uilang0.c
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\tools\msys64\tmp\cclvYTlj.o:uilang0.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `GetUILanguageFallbackList'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

There is a muiload.lib with the Windows SDK, but I can't find an equivalent for MinGW-w64, even though it does provide the muiload.h header file. I tried linking with that; that fixed the above linker error but introduced even more linker errors:
# gcc -o uilang0 uilang0.c /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/minkernel/crts/crtw32/misc/nt/objfre/amd64/guard_support.obj):(.00cfg[__guard_check_icall_fptr]+0x0): undefined reference to `_guard_check_icall_nop'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/minkernel/crts/crtw32/misc/nt/objfre/amd64/guard_support.obj):(.00cfg[__guard_xfg_check_icall_fptr]+0x0): undefined reference to `_guard_check_icall_nop'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.text$mn+0xe): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.text$mn+0x92): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.text$mn+0x13): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.text$mn+0xfb): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$?PreVistaFallback@@YAHKPEAKPEAG0@Z]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/getuilanguagefallbacklist.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$?MultiStr_AddLangAndParentNames@@YAHPEAG_KG@Z]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
C:/tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/muiload.lib(d:/os/obj/amd64fre/onecore/base/mui/muiload/lib/objfre/amd64/multistr.obj):(.text$mn+0x7f): undefined reference to `StringCchCopyW'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried adding a bunch more Platform SDK .lib files, but no matter what combination I use, I still get undefined references. Adding BufferOverflowU.lib gets rid of the undefined reference to __security_cookie/__security_check_cookie. Adding ntdllp.lib gets rid of the undefined reference to __GSHandlerCheck. But I can't seem to get rid of the _guard_check_icall_nop or StringCchCopyW undefined references. Also, I can't help but worry that randomly adding libraries without knowing what I'm doing, even if I eventually get it to link, it might not work due to some incompatible combination.

minGW Windows headers are not official, rewritten by hand. They notoriously miss recent or less used definitions such as this function. You'll have to define it yourself (probably the most simple way) or use a compiler that supports the official Windows SDK

@SimonMourier: the function is in the MinGW headers, that isn't the problem. This isn't a header problem, it is a linker problem.

In my Visual Studio, StringCchCopyW is defined inline in the strsafe.h header (a nice little 10.000 line thingy).

That changes nothing, headers or libs, same fight

@BoP: MinGW-w64's version of strsafe.h defines StringCchCopyW inline too. But inline definitions in headers seem irrelevant because the Platform SDK's muiload.lib refers to it as an external symbol.

Maybe I'm blind, but I do not see a valid use case for MinGW. What part can the MinGW tools play in delivering quality solutions?

@IInspectable If you are porting software from Linux (especially non-GUI software such as command line tools), MinGW is a lot less of a learning curve than Visual Studio.

Hacky, but I got it to work. First, create the file fakeapi.c with the contents:
#define DEPRECATE_SUPPORTED
#include <strsafe.h>

__attribute__((weak))
STRSAFEAPI StringCchCopyW(STRSAFE_LPWSTR pszDest,size_t cchDest,STRSAFE_LPCWSTR pszSrc) {
  if(cchDest > STRSAFE_MAX_CCH) return STRSAFE_E_INVALID_PARAMETER;
  return StringCopyWorkerW(pszDest,cchDest,pszSrc);
}

__attribute__((fastcall))
extern void _guard_check_icall_nop(uintptr_t Target) {
  ((void)Target);
}

And then do:
gcc -o uilang0.exe uilang0.c \
    /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64/{muiload,BufferOverflowU,ntdllp}.lib \
    fakeapi.c \
    -Wl,--section-start=.retplne=0x141000000

The resulting uilang0.exe won't work. However, let's edit it using objcopy to remove the .retplne section:
objcopy --remove-section=.retplne ./uilang0.exe

Probably, instead of using objcopy --remove-section=, should edit the linker script to DISCARD the .retplne section.
The resulting uilang0.exe executes successfully. Furthermore, the GetUILanguageFallbackList API actually works, as demonstrated by the below enhanced version of uilang0.c:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <muiload.h>

noreturn void fatal(const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: %s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}

noreturn void fatal_error(const char* op) {
    fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: %s failed with error: %lu\n", op, GetLastError());
    exit(1);
}

void* xmalloc(size_t size) {
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL) fatal("memory allocation failed");
    return ptr;
}

void *xrealloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
    ptr = realloc(ptr, size);
    if (ptr == NULL) fatal("memory allocation failed");
    return ptr;
}

char* ConvertUTF16ToUTF8(const wchar_t* utf16Str) {
    int utf8Len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16Str, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (utf8Len == 0) return NULL;
    char* utf8Str = (char*)xmalloc(utf8Len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16Str, -1, utf8Str, utf8Len, NULL, NULL);
    return utf8Str;
}

int main() {
    ULONG bufferSize = 256;
    wchar_t* fallbackList = (wchar_t*)xmalloc(bufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
    ULONG fallbackListSize;
    if (!GetUILanguageFallbackList(fallbackList, bufferSize, &fallbackListSize)) fatal_error("GetUILanguageFallbackList");
    if (fallbackListSize > bufferSize) {
        fallbackList = (wchar_t*)xrealloc(fallbackList, fallbackListSize * sizeof(wchar_t));
        if (!GetUILanguageFallbackList(fallbackList, fallbackListSize, &fallbackListSize)) fatal_error("GetUILanguageFallbackList");
    }
    char* utf8Str = ConvertUTF16ToUTF8(fallbackList);
    if (utf8Str == NULL) fatal("UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion failed");
    printf("UI Language Fallback List: %s\n", utf8Str);
    free(fallbackList);
    free(utf8Str);
    return 0;
}

On my system, running that prints out:
UI Language Fallback List: en-GB

